# A legacy parsing error in Boto3 script due to MalformedPolicyDocument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, boto

I am trying to create an IAM user on AWS and attach, it to a User group with IAM policies,but I am getting "An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: The policy failed legacy parsing" error, I am not sure what it means. I think it has to do with the policy itself, but I am not sure.

```
import boto3
import sys
import json
iam = boto3.client('iam')
sts = boto3.client('sts')

response = iam.create_user(
    UserName='GoodUser'
)
IDK = sts.get_caller_identity()
print(IDK['UserId'])
response = iam.create_group(
    GroupName='GoodGroup'
)

response = iam.add_user_to_group(
    GroupName='GoodGroup',
    UserName='GoodUser'
)

some_policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{}:instance/*".format(IDK),
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{}:security-group/*".format(IDK),
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{}:image/ami-0a91cd140a1fc148a".format(IDK)
            ],
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{}:instance/*".format(IDK),
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} 
response = iam.create_policy(
  PolicyName='GoodPolicy',
  PolicyDocument=json.dumps(some_policy)
)
print(response)

IDK1 = iam.attach_user_policy(
    UserName='GoodUser',
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::{}:policy/some_policy'.format(IDK)
)
```

Comment: try to create the policy via the AWS console. Use the output of `json.dumps(some_policy)` as input

Comment: That won't work for my use case because I will need the UserID and it might change for every user so don't want to hardcode them in the policy

Comment: use a fake id if possible and maybe you will get a feedback from the console about what is wrong

Comment: I have tested the policy with console and it works with hard coded UserID but when I try to enter dynamically on boto it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error might be related to your `IDK` variable.

`IDK = sts.get_caller_identity()` returns a dict of following format:

```
{
    'UserId': 'string',
    'Account': 'string',
    'Arn': 'string'
}
```

Later you use this object to format resource strings: `"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{}:instance/*".format(IDK)`
This will produce invalid principals. I suspect you might have intended to do something like this: `f"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:{IDK['Account']}:instance/*"` (using f-string instead of `str.format`, result is the same).